# ReactLeaflet with open street map- unable to fit in marker point exactly inside the image overlay

Tags: image, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I am trying to fit an imageoverlay inside a map container with few marker points to be aligned accordingly.

outer/div container size is  fixed height: "264px" width: "1179px",imageoverlay here is an image of airport bay with list of  latitudes and longitude points for each bay locations,

I have 4 point coordinates of entire bay area which is to be covered, Problem is if I try to fit the image inside the 4 points image looks distorted, all the markers appears close to each other, and also it is not aligned with image overlay. I tried to rotate the image even then it didnt work.(2nd image for ref)

If I fit the image overlay based on the width/height image fits well, but markers are all scattered ,
Help is much appreciated , kindly excuse if the above explanation quite long.(1st image for ref)

[unaligned markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6AnW.png)
[proper_markers_OSM_but_not_correctly_as_in_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0VZU.png)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {useMemo,render,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { LatLng, LatLngBounds,CRS,Transformation } from "leaflet";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, ImageOverlay ,Marker, Popup,useMap,Rectangle, ZoomControl} from "react-leaflet";
import {data} from "./data/mockdata"
import aiportviewmap from './data/aiportviewmap.png'

const Bound = () => {

  const outerBounds = [
      [1.3395283985838653, 103.97021804850274],
      [1.3875520864854187, 103.99121729409903],
      [1.3316406520024404, 103.98991242756328],
      [1.3820307764687148, 104.00684534524635],
  ] 

  function SetBoundsRectangles() {
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(outerBounds)
    let calcbound=[];
    data.map((row) =>{
        calcbound.push([row.northLat,row.eastLong])
    })
    const bayBound=calcbound
    const map = useMap()  
    useEffect(()=>{
      map.setView( [map.getCenter().lat, map.getCenter().lng],15)    
      // // map.invalidateSize();    
      // //   setBounds(outerBounds)
      //  map.fitBounds(outerBounds)
    },[])

    return (
      <>
        <ImageOverlay
          // url={"https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"}
          style={{ transform:'rotate(180deg)' }}
          url={aiportviewmap}
          bounds={ outerBounds}
          // eventHandlers={innerHandlers}
          opacity={0.8}
          zIndex={10}
          scale={1}       
          style={{transform:"rotate(90deg)" }} 
           whenReady={(e) => e.target.fitBounds(bayBound)} 
        />
      </>
    )
  } 

  return(
    <MapContainer 
     center ={[1.3595963692439295,103.98853169687455]} 
     zoom={0}  
     // style={{ transform:"rotate(90deg)" }}
     scrollWheelZoom={false}    
     crs={CRS.Simple}>
     <TileLayer
       attribution='&copy; <a   href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
       url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"  />
     <SetBoundsRectangles />
       {data.map((row) => {
         console.log("row",row);
         return (          
           <Marker 
             key={row.bayLocationCode}
             position={[row.northLat, row.eastLong]}>
             <Popup>
               {row.bayLocationCode}
             </Popup>
            </Marker>);
         })
       }
    </MapContainer>
  )
} 

export default Bound;
```

Comment: It sounds like the coordinates you are using to georeference your image overlay are wrong.  Where did they come from?  What does it mean that "If I fit the image overlay based on the width/height image fits well"?  Either the coordinates on your markers are wrong, or the coordinates on your image overlay are wrong.  This sounds like a data issue, not a code issue

Comment: @SethLutske,pls note this is static image , not an georeferenced one, bounds represent 4 points(nw,ne,sw,se) of an airport location, In which I am trying to fit an static image , Is that even possible. Please let me know in react-leaflet is there any option to fit an image over OSM where reducing the opacity the image should be aligned to the underlying map. Pls correct me if am wrong somewhere.